# redirect user to a new page after verification his email laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel project , user will register new account and then the system will send verification email to verify his email , every things going perfect , but I want to redirect user to another page after he verified his email , so in

> VerificationController

I  can change the value of redirectTo variable ,

```
   protected $redirectTo =  RouteServiceProvider::admin;
```

but  I want to pass the user's id  in the URL , I tried to add

```
auth()->user()->id;
```

but I get error

> expression is not allowed as field default value

so how can I pass user's id to redirect URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel < 7.0 or Laravel > 7.0 in combination with Laravel-ui you can use the following.

Instead of using the `$redirectTo` property, you can add a `redirectTo` method instead:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    return '/admin/' . auth()->user()->id;
}
```

Source:

[Laravel < 7.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RedirectsUsers.php#L12)

[Laravel-ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/auth-backend/RedirectsUsers.php)

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```